# Sharepoint Excel Services Recycling the App Pool

Tags: sharepoint, excel, service

I have a question regarding sharepoint excel web services session handling. What happens if we recycle the app pool. If an application has opened an excel workbook programmatically using excel web services, would restarting the app pool or re-setting the IIS have any affect.

Thanking you in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

If you restart the app pool the session stored in memory in Excel Services backend will no longer exist and therefore any request against that session will fail.